# How to find rows with same time intervals in pandas fataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am locating beaconing activities in DNS records, and I have the pandas dataframe containing parsed DNS records.

The structure looks like this:

```
     Received_Time       Sender_IP  Receiver_IP  Content
2019-01-01 23:59:54.999   0.0.0.1     1.1.1.1      ...
2019-01-01 23:59:56.999   0.0.0.1     1.1.1.1      ...
2019-01-01 23:59:57.999   0.0.0.1     1.1.1.1      ...
2019-01-01 23:59:58.999   0.0.0.1     1.1.1.1      ...
2019-01-01 23:59:59.999   0.0.0.1     1.1.1.2      ...
```

And I am trying to achieve:

```
Beacon_Interval(s)  Beacon_Count(including first)  Sender_IP  Receiver_IP
      1.000                      3                  0.0.0.1     1.1.1.1
```

Time is in datetime type, my thinking is:

1. Add a column of "time interval to last query".
2. Then it's easy to count and find senders who sent most queries with the same intervals.

I am not sure how to do the first step. And I am also posting to see if anyone has better ways to achieve the task, thank you in advance.

Comment: where is `Beacon_Interval(s)` and `Beacon_Count(including first)` in your dataframe

Comment: That's something I am trying to add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based from what I understand, you wanna get the interval of each 'Received Time' which can be done by this:

```
df['Beacon_Interval(s)'] = df['Received_Time'].diff().dt.seconds
```

Since we now know the 'Beacon Intervals' we can then count their number of instances using this code:

```
#Note, since you explicitly tell that it should count the first instance, I used +2 instead of +1 in the end.
df['Beacon_Count(including first)'] = \
df.groupby((df['Beacon_Interval(s)'] != df['Beacon_Interval(s)'].shift(1)).cumsum()).cumcount()+2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The `diff()` and `cumcount()` are what I am looking for. One thing to mention is that I need to first group by "Receiver_IP" (since beaconing records are recognized as those sending to same servers) and then run your steps. That's why my count is 3, and beacons are 2-4 rows, as the last one sends to a different receiver (1.1.1.2).

Comment: Glad it helped out. As for the groupby thing, you didn't specify it in your question, sorry about that. If I managed to helped you out, please click on the checkmark beside my answer to accept it